# Kafka node skip bad offset

Tags: javascript, node.js, apache-kafka

i have a proyect and every time that the data send it to the consumer are wrong the script throws this error "Unexpected token a in JSON at position 0", I need to know if is posible to step foward to the next offset that not produces this error. Could someone help me with this?
Thanks.

Comment: Please add some code. So we could help you to find what's wrong with it.

Comment: Probably your json format is not correct somewhere